# How to implement the folder tree in the left of finder?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, finder

I just like to implement a function : Develope a app , and have a outline view, which have a folder and file tree just like Finder or a app called PathFinder , how to implement it ? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's called a source list, and there's a really convenient `NSOutlineView` subclass available on github here:  http://github.com/Perspx/PXSourceList